# How to convert sequence of ply files to .fbx animation

Tags: python, animation, 3d, fbx

I have a sequence of meshes in .ply format. I am looking to convert this sequence into a .fbx animation, where each frame of animation is represented by one ply file.

I looked around but couldn't find anything. I am very 3d animation, would be glad if you have any suggestions on how to convert sequence of ply to fbx animation.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using blender and the [stop motion obj addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/stop-motion-obj-obj-stl-ply-sequence-importer-v2-1-1/670105?page=2).